# Cannot disable QLabel transparency in PyQt6

Tags: qt, pyqt, label, transparency, qtstylesheets

I have an app that contains a window. No modifications to the default styles have been made.

I want a QLabel to appear when I hover over a particular item in a table, in a datatip style
No matter how I apply the stylesheets, I am not able to render the background of the label fully opaque.

In particular, when I use the following lines:

```
stylesheet = "QLabel{opacity:1; background: red; border: 1px solid white};"

label.setStyleSheet(window_stylesheet)
```

What I obtain is something like this:

[image: Image appearing transparent]

I'm on OSX. How do I render the label fully opaque?

**EDIT:**
As requested in the comments, here is a MWE showing how the label is created.

```py
# hello.py

"""Simple Hello, World example with PyQt6."""

import sys
# 1. Import QApplication and all the required widgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QComboBox, QPushButton, QStyle, QStyleFactory
# hello.py
# ...

data = {
    "col1": ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    "col2": ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    "col3": ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    "col4": ['1', '2', '3', '4']
}

 
class myTableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setData(data)
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        stylesheet  = "QTableView:item{border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)}"
        stylesheet_hovered  = "QTableView:item:hover{background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)}"
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet_hovered)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.current_hover = [0, 0]
        self.cellEntered.connect(self.cellHover)

 
    def setData(self, data): 
        self.data = data
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(list(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def cellHover(self, row, column):
        item = self.item(row, column)
        old_item = self.item(self.current_hover[0], self.current_hover[1])

        infodict = {
            x: self.data[x][row] for x in list(self.data.keys())
        }
        if self.current_hover != [row,column]:
            if self.datatip.explaination_thread is not None:
                self.datatip.cancelExplaination()     # Cancel old datatip
        
            self.datatip.showExplaination(infodict)

        self.current_hover = [row, column]


class registerDataTip(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setText('DATATIP')
        self.explaination_thread = None
        self.close()

    def showExplaination(self, infodict):
        self.setText(f'<b>{infodict["col1"]}</b><br>This is a test string<br>I should be opaque but I am not')
        self.adjustSize()
        # self.explaination_thread = setTimeout(1, self.show)
        self.show()

    def cancelExplaination(self):
        self.close()


        # self.show()

# 2. Create an instance of QApplication
app = QApplication([])

# 3. Create your application's GUI
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("PyQt App")
# window.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) # won't work on windows style.

window.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 80)

window_stylesheet = "QLabel{opacity:1; background: red; border: 1px solid white;};"

app.setStyleSheet(window_stylesheet)
#app.setStyleSheet(label_stylesheet)

table_meaning = myTableView(data,  len(data[list(data.keys())[0]]), len(list(data.keys())), window)
label_meaning = registerDataTip(window)
label_meaning.move(800,500)
table_meaning.datatip = label_meaning
table_meaning.setGeometry(60, 100, 600, 800)

random_button = QPushButton(window)
random_button.move(800,500)


# 4. Show your application's GUI
window.showMaximized()

# 5. Run your application's event loop
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With the result:

[image: This does not work]

Comment: How is created the label? Please provide a [mre]. Besides, why don't you just use tool tips?

Comment: @musicamante I edited the original post with a MWE. I am not using tooltips because the handling of the conditions for the appearing/disappearing of the tooltip are quite complex, and in general I found the PyQt6 documentation a bit dispersive. Maybe eventually I'll switch to ToolTips, but I cannot get why the current label appears transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label **is** opaque.

The problem is that you are setting the same parent for it and the button that is created *after* it. Since they share the same parent, the *last* created widget is always shown on top of the widget stack.

Just add the following line *after* the button is created:

```
label_meaning.raise_()
```

Note that your handling of that "datatip" is quite unorthodox, especially considering that that widget is managed from an unrelated one, and it should *not* be responsibility of the table to manage an object that is not its child.

A more appropriate solution would be to create a custom signal, and connect it externally:

```py
class MyTableView(QTableWidget):
    showTip = pyqtSignal(dict)
    # ...
    def cellHover(self, row, column):
        infodict = {
            x: self.data[x][row] for x in list(self.data.keys())
        }
        if self.current_hover != [row,column]:
            self.showTip.emit(infodict)
        self.current_hover = [row, column]


class RegisterDataTip(QLabel):
    # ...
    def showExplaination(self, infodict):
        if self.explaination_thread is not None:
            self.cancelExplaination()
        
        self.setText('''
            <b>{}</b><br>
            This is a test string<br>
            I <b>am</b> opaque
        '''.format(infodict["col1"]))

        self.adjustSize()
        self.show()
        self.raise_()


# ...
table_meaning.showTip.connect(label_meaning.showExplaination)
```

<sup>Note that the CSS also has a syntax error (the last semicolon). That said, your explanation about not using QToolTip doesn't seem sufficient for your case. Just read the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html) (not the PyQt one). Finally, please don't use lowercase names for classes, that's a terrible choice: classes and constants should **always** be capitalized, in order to easily tell classes/constants and functions/variables apart.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your precious suggestions, I'm about to mark this answer as correct. However, I cannot explain why the label appears translucent and not fully covered by the button.

Comment: It's not the label that is translucent, it's the button that has an alpha channel and allows to "see through", because that's apparently how buttons are made in the macOS style.